# How to display only selected tab layout in Android created using TabHost

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs

I've created a tabbed based application.
There are **4 Tabs**, I've created 4 Activities

(**HomeActivity**, **SettingsActivity**, **LicenseActivity** and **AboutActivity**)

for the 4 Tabs, with a **MainActivity**. I'm setting the selected Activity as **HomeActivity** I've designed my all 4 Activities when I run the application and whichever Tab I select all the designs of all 4 Activities are displayed.

How can I display the layout of only selected Tab?

**Example:** when I select **Settings Tab** then only **SettingsActivity** layout should display..

My codes is as following:
**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources ressources = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

        // Home tab
        Intent intentHome = new Intent().setClass(this, HomeActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecHome = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Home")
            .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_home_config))
            .setContent(intentHome);

        // Settings tab
        Intent intentSettings = new Intent().setClass(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecSettings = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Settings")
            .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_settings_config))
            .setContent(intentSettings);

        // License tab
        Intent intentLicense = new Intent().setClass(this, LicenseActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecLicense = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("License")
            .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_license_config))
            .setContent(intentLicense);

        // About tab
        Intent intentAbout = new Intent().setClass(this, AboutActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecAbout = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("About")
            .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_about_config))
            .setContent(intentAbout);

        // add all tabs 
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecHome);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecSettings);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecLicense);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAbout);

        //set Home tab as default (zero based)
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <!-- android:background="#34282C" -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <include layout="@layout/home"/>
            <include layout="@layout/settings"/>
            <include layout="@layout/license"/>
            <include layout="@layout/about"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**icon_home_config.xml** and same for other Activities

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_home"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_home" />
</selector>
```

**home.xml** (Here I wanna provide Login form with 2 EditText and a button) and some layout for other Activities

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I need to add in my code and where exactly I've to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your main.xml file, set

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" >
        <include layout="@layout/home"/>
        <include layout="@layout/settings"/>
        <include layout="@layout/license"/>
        <include layout="@layout/about"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

to

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" >
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for replying.. when I remove the `<include>` tag it doesn't display anything....

Comment: please remove tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); or please follow http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/